# X11 forwarding not working for same id, signed by different people

Tags: x11, putty, mobaxterm

2 users both sign onto the linux box with the same id.   X11 forwarding works for one and not the other  We tried both putty and mobaxterm.  We think we verified all the options between the 2 users.  All the settings in putty and mobaxterm look the same between the 2 users.  But x11 forwarding works for one and not the other.

Comment: Once connection is established, what are the values of the DISPLAY environment variable for both users? And in the failing case, if you try to start a simple X11 application like `xclock` or `xterm`, what is the error message displayed when the forwarding fails? Is SSH key authentication used, and if it is, does each user has a separate SSH key? (It's possible to specify per-key restrictions in the `authorized_keys` file on the remote host.)

Comment: We each use a different vdi,   my display=w10vsasfc606 and his  =w0vsasfc602, we both use the same rsa key but it is on each of our vdis.   we use the same id to sign on to the linux box.  if I type in xclock or xterm,  it tells me command not found

Answer (score 0):

If you are manually setting the DISPLAY variable on the remote host, you will be using old-school unencrypted networked X11. It might be a bit faster than SSH-forwarded X11, but completely without any meaningful security. If you do this, you will have to handle any X11 authentication yourself, either by getting a X11 session cookie passed from the local workstation to the remote host's `xauth` command, or by disabling X11 authentication on the local workstation (on unix-like systems, this classically means using the `xhost` command; on Windows X11 display servers there might be a GUI for this).

In this mode, the X11 application on the remote host needs to be able to resolve the hostname in the `DISPLAY` variable so the remote application will be able to contact the local workstation, and any intervening network firewalls must allow the connection from the remote host to the local workstation's TCP port (6000 + the DISPLAY number). If any of this fails, there will be no X11 graphics displayed from the remote host. Beyond the initial start-up of the remote X11 application, the SSH connection will not be involved with the GUI at all.

---

When actually using SSH X11 forwarding, the DISPLAY variable on the remote host should be automatically set to something like `localhost:10.0` (the number part may vary, but the first number will normally be equal or greater than 10). When you configure a SSH client to request X11 forwarding, the `sshd` server on the remote host will create a X11 proxy that will listen for X11 connections locally, and forward the connection inside the SSH encrypted tunnel to the local workstation, where the SSH client will pass it on to the local X11 display server software. The X11 session cookie will also be handled automatically by the SSH client and the `sshd` server.